# Trying to create processes with fork()

Tags: c, linux, fork, pid

So I am trying to create multiple processes using `fork()`, like this:

[image: process tree]

I tried multiple ways but never achieved what I need.
This is the closest I got.

```
if (fork() == 0) {
    int father = getpid();
    
    printf("father son: %d %d\n", father, getpid());
    if (fork() == 0) {
        printf("father son: %d %d\n", getppid(), getpid());
    }
    if (getpid() == father && fork() == 0) {
        printf("father son: %d %d\n", getppid(), getpid());
    }
} else {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        printf("father son: %d %d\n", getppid(), getpid());
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `father = getpid()` looks wrong.  I'm pretty sure you meant `father = getppid()`.

Comment: You will probably want each process that forks any children to `wait()` for them before terminating.  Otherwise, some parent processes may terminate before their children get around to calling `getppid()`.  That's not inherently wrong, but it interferes with verifying that you've managed to create the correct process tree.

Comment: Finally, note that the original process and its first child each want to fork exactly two children, but you use different control-flow logic for that in the two cases.  Why?

Comment: Thank you for your kind help, I've read your tips and was able to create the tree required.